# Whch controls "restart" numbering for TabIndex?

Tags: .net, winforms, tabindex

I know that the tab indices are relative to parent controls, but I can't find the documentation listing *which* controls do this.

The only remotely relevant things I found on MSDN were that tabbing through a form will only land on the active `RadioButton` of a set, and that `TabPage.TabIndex` does nothing because you change page with the arrow keys.

In case it's important, I'm working on a WinForms project targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 (incl. Mono).

Comment: see: [ContainerControl Class - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly, it says inheritors of `ContainerControl` can't be tabbed *to* (as if they had `TabStop = false`). Some controls including `GroupBox` have this nesting behaviour but don't inherit `ContainerControl`, so that can't be related.

Comment: Container controls generally don't receive the focus.  While the GroupBox doesn't inherit from a ContainerControl, it does have `SetStyle(ControlStyles.ContainerControl, true);` and `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);` A PictureBox isn't selectable either, by default. What problem are you actually trying to resolve?

Comment: I'm just looking for the docs. I originally wanted to simplify the tab order on a form with about a hundred controls, but I solved that by trial-and-error as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VS Community's form designer (which has `View` > `Tab Order`), it seems like each of the "Container" controls does this, giving this (incomplete?) list:

- `Form` (ofc)
- `GroupBox`
- `Panel`

  - `FlowLayoutPanel`
  - `SplitterPanel`
  - `TableLayoutPanel`
  - `TabPage` (the designer generates assignments to `TabIndex` even though [you can't change the active page with the tab key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabpage.tabindex?view=netframework-4.8#remarks))
- `SplitContainer`
- `TabControl`

As an example, a `TextBox` in a `GroupBox` in a `TabPage` in a `TabControl` (in a `Form`) might be displayed as index `0.2.5.1` in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question is controls which are knows as **Containers** in the toolbox: *Panel*, *TableLayoutPanel*, *FlowLayoutPanel*, *SplitContainer*, *GroupBox*, *TabControl*.

You can see the behavior in design-mode, by selecting the design surface, then from *View* menu, select *Tab Order*.

---

You may also want to consider some special tab behaviors of the controls:

- Container controls like *Panel*, *GroupBox*, *TableLayoutPanel*, *FlowLayoutPanel*, *SplitContainer*, *Form*: While the container control itself will not be selected by <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, but their tab index determines the next control group which will be selected by <kbd>Tab</kbd>. It means tab order of their children will be resolved based on the parent. Setting `TabStop` property to `true` or `false` for the container doesn't have any impact on tab order.
- *UserControl*: Acts like container controls described above with a difference. It respects to `TabStop` property, so if it's `TabStop` is false, it's child control will not be selected by <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
- *TabControl*: <kbd>Tab</kbd> will select controls of the selected tab page and skip rest of the tab pages. To switch between tab pages, you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.
- *RadioButton* controls in a container control: <kbd>Tab</kbd> will stop just on checked radio button and skip rest of them.
- *DataGridView*: Has a `StandardTab` property which is `false` by default. When it's false, when the control receives <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it selects the `CurrentCell` cell and then pressing more <kbd>Tab</kbd> will select next cell utill the last cell. Then selects next control. If the property is set to `true`, the behavior is standard and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> on control, selects next control.
- *TextBox*, *RichTextBox*: They have an `AcceptsTab` property which is false by default. When it's false the behavior is standard and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will select next control. If set to `true`, <kbd>Tab</kbd> key inserts a tab character in them rather than moving to next control.
- *ToolStrip*, *StatusStrip*, *MenuStrip*: If their `TabStop` property is `false`, when they somehow receive focus, then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> key just rotates between selectable tool strip items and will not pass to the next control. But if theit `TabStop` is `true` then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will select their first selectable item. Further <kbd>Tab</kbd> press on them will select the next selectable control (inside or outside of the strip).
- *PropertyGrid*: When you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> on this control, it selects the property label, then editing area and then if there is a edit button, selects the edit button and then selects the next control.
- *LinkLabel* Receives <kbd>Tab</kbd> in case it contains a link area, otherwise will not receive tab.

Comment: Just some relevant document: [How to: Set the Tab Order on Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/bd16a8cw(v=vs.90))

Comment: [ContainerControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).